# Handling POSTed multipart/form-data file

Tags: python, falconframework

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle POSTed raw data on the server side. 
So I'm using Falconframework and I'm able to receive user submitted file

```
-----------------------------1209846671886287098156775745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

d3ad452e-a287-4cb7-ac1f-f0a5cdb54386
-----------------------------1209846671886287098156775745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfilename"

Screenshot.png
-----------------------------1209846671886287098156775745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

1951677
-----------------------------1209846671886287098156775745                                                                                         
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="Screenshot.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG
.................lots of bites............
```

Using python and hopefully some other lib i would like to turn it into some sort of file object which i can extract metadata - filename , uuid etc, as well as the file itself. 
Which lib should i use?

Comment: it is a basic stuff that should be provided by your web framework something like `request.files.get('file-input-name')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian , yep i thought i would be sth quite basic , but unfortunatelly falconframework is yet to implement this in upcoming releases. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You could implement it yourself using `cgi.FieldStorage`, e.g., see [`bottle.py` does it](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L1187)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a middle ware project that looks promising I'm currently trying to implement this myself in a falcon service.

[falcon-multipart](https://github.com/yohanboniface/falcon-multipart)

I have have pretty good luck as well using cgi.FeildStorage(). As found in the following post.
[cgi article](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/245292/Falcon-hook-for-multipart-form-data-(POC)

```
import cgi

def on_post(req, resp):
    env = req.env
    env.setdefault('QUERY_STRING','')
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=req.stream,environ=env)
    form['fileinputname'].file
```

If you are willing to have one non falcon hook here is an example with bottle:
[example](http://Here%20is%20an%20example%20using%20bottle%20[bottle%20example][3])

Comment: That works for me, too, and releases the burden of integrating a third party middleware into my API. By the way, it might be useful to know that you can call `.read()` on the return value of `form['fileinputname'].file` in order to get the content as bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a very late followup to this old discussion.

As of [Falcon 3.0](https://pypi.org/project/falcon/3.0.0), the framework [supports `multipart/form-data` natively](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/multipart.html) for both [WSGI](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/app.html#wsgi-app) and [ASGI applications](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/app.html#asgi-app).